# Sharepoint 2010 - Delete Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

I had picture library on Sharepoint with 500MB of images. I have deleted it from site and farm level also. But data still rely on SQL DB. I have daily backups on server. Before uploading images daily backup were 14MB. after i have upload images backup was increased to 500MB. I have deleted that picture library. Even cleared the recycle bin from farm level too. But SQL Daily backup still takes 500MB. Can anyone please help me to release unwanted sql data.
(Shrinking database also not resoved the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first delete the library, then delete if from the site's recycle bin. Finally remove it from the second stage recycle bin as well. Example using PowerShell

```
# $SiteCol is the site collection of the library
# This will remove all items in the second stage recycle bin
$SiteCol.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();
```